# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Failed to parse: proxy:port

Tags: proxy

I wanted to install a package using pip3 but that's happened:

```
Ubuntu@User:~$ pip3 install <package-name>
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Failed to parse: https://<proxy>:<port>/
```

Can someone help me what should i do? I think that I should change the proxy settings, but how?

Comment: Is there an HTTPS_PROXY variable in your environment?

Comment: @steeldriver It was, I removed so basicly it can return to default!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it was proxy configuration, Problem solved!

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy

unset http_proxy
unset ftp_proxy
unset all_proxy
unset https_proxy
unset no_proxy
```